# Cakephp sending email to checked customer

Tags: email, cakephp, checkbox

Is it possible to have checkbox in the customer table where Admin can tick who he want to send email? For example he wants to send email to John and Patrick, all he has to do is Tick John and Patrick and click on send email button. Is it possible to do in cakephp? I have been googling but cannot find the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the ids of the users you've checked and from the ids you can get their email addresses and then simply do a foreach() to send an email to all selected users or put them into an email queue system.